# Bad version of db2jcc.jar used with JRE 1.7?

Tags: java, tomcat, db2

**Solution Found**: I wound up putting db2jcc4.jar on Tomcat 8 in the Tomcat lib folder and we're good to go. Same doesn't work for Tomcat7 however, so I took the db2jcc.jar out of the project external jar references and let the server determine which version to use instead

**Original Question**

Googling has produced a slew of cryptic references for this question: which version of db2jcc to use with jre 1.7.

[This page lists the driver downloads](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866) by db2 version, but not JRE.

The problem that led me to this mystery is we have two Tomcat servers, one running JRE 1.8 and one running 1.7.  Oddly enough, the former is running Tomcat 7 and the later Tomcat 8. (you can ask but I don't have an answer for this)

So our development code is running fine making connections to db2 from our Tomcat 7 JRE 1.8 system, but other things deployed to our Tomcat 8 JRE 1.7 server are feared breakable by updating to JRE 1.8 there, so we suspect an error, shown below, to be a version mismatch between JRE 1.7 and our db2jcc.jar file.

Perhaps it is a problem with Tomcat 8, though.

The error, extracted from the stack trace:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.isValid(I)Z
```

Now a final wrinkle, the project that I have developed and tested on Tomcat 7 JRE 1.8 is built in Eclipse with JRE 1.7 compliance. So why would we get this error?  Does it appear to be a version compatibility issue?

More complete (but not full) stack trace

```
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 root cause javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.isValid(I)Z
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:908)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:837)
    org.apache.jsp.getTimesheetsForUser_jsp._jspService(getTimesheetsForUser_jsp.java:112)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    root cause java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.isValid(I)Z
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:913)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:226)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:302)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2208)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2191)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1945)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1412)
    com.hr.timesheets.JDBCConnection.queryProdData(JDBCConnection.java:226)
    com.hr.timesheets.TimeSheetQueryManager.getTimesheets(TimeSheetQueryManager.java:624)
    com.hr.timesheets.TimeSheetQueryManager.generateUploadsForUser(TimeSheetQueryManager.java:343)
    org.apache.jsp.getTimesheetsForUser_jsp._jspService(getTimesheetsForUser_jsp.java:94)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Can anyone see something obvious here that our team is missing?  Anyone else have this problem before?

Note:  we are using pooled connection resources configured in our context.iml file, as shown here:

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
name="jdbc/hrdb2"
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
url="jdbc:db2://hrdb2.hr.com:50200/time"
username="redacted" 
password="redacted"
maxIdle="10"
maxActive="400"
maxWait="5"
removeAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="1200"
/>
```

Comment: Looks like incompatibility between versions of the DB2 driver. Make sure you have the same one in Eclipse as you have in the two Tomcats.

Comment: It's included in the project .war file, but your suggestion was good - searching the C: drive on the first machine where things work reveals two copies in the apache path, one in an AXIS2 webapp, and the other in my application path.  A third is in a completely separate path for a separate tool.  Only my application is deployed to the prod server.  Could the Tomcat Classloader be finding the other instance first and using it instead of the jar in the application path?

Comment: I have no reason to suspect these are different versions, however.  So what I'm using should be the same on each server.

Comment: I see two possibilities - one is that the two servers use the same code, but one of them is using an old, incompatible driver. The other is that the newer Tomcat is using an operation that exists in newer drivers, but you supplied it with an old driver that is the same as the one you use for Tomcat 7. How about trying the latest driver?

Comment: I wound up putting db2jcc4.jar on Tomcat 8 in the Tomcat lib folder and we're good to go.  Same doesn't work for Tomcat7 however, so I took the db2jcc.jar out of the project external jar references and let the server determine which version to use instead.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered in the comments and update above.

Specifically: putting the jar file known to work with a given Tomcat release in the lib folder on the server, and removing it from the application, allows the server to handle the connectivity instead of the application, especially as we use connection pooling.

So we can put db2jcc.jar on tomcat 7 and db2jcc4.jar on tomcat 8 and the application code need not change when deploying to either server.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very tough time when upgraded my db2 driver version, I had db2jcc4 dependency in my POM.xml and locating it through system path ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/db2jcc-db2jcc4.jar
also in my wepapp/WEB-INF/lib folder I had the proper db2 jar sitting there but was still getting the same error mentioned above.
I am using Intellij Idea as my IDE and missed out a little detail i.e. to remove the old dependency of db2 that I set from project settings > libraries, where my project was still pointing to db2jcc old version, removed that old library from there and my project started running again.