# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.isValid(I)Z

Tags: java, jdbc, abstract-methods

Good evening,

I'm whith a problem on a project whith EJB Timer, I don't know what can I do to fix it.

there are a few methods in my project, all of them works well except "CargaC" When I call it I get a msg error:

My code:

```
public void CargaC() {
        Connection db2 = null;
        DadosCDao dadosCDao = new DadosCDao();
        try{
            if(db2 == null || db2.isClosed()){
                if((db2==null)||(db2.isClosed())){
                    db2 = new Dao().conexaoDb23();
                    if(!db2.isValid(5)){
                        db2 = new Dao().conexaoDb2K();
                        if(!db2.isValid(5)){
                            db2 = new Dao().conexaoDb2R();
                        }
                    }
                }
                ArrayList<DadosC> lista = dadosCDao.cargaDadosDb2(db2);
                if(!lista.isEmpty()){
                    verificaDados(lista);
                }

            }
            db2.close();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Projeto PrjX, classe CargaDadosC, método cargaC, erro: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

error msg:

```
12:10:18,147 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.3)
12:10:18,168 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 4.0)
12:10:18,180 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /PrjX
12:10:18,380 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018559: Deployed "PrjX.war"
12:12:10,138 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 9) JBAS014120: Error invoking timeout for timer: [id=bc427e5b-d2f3-425b-9c13-2878e69b596a timedObjectId=PrjX.PrjX.CargaDadosC auto-timer?:true persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@2fa3858f initialExpiration=Thu May 12 06:00:00 BRT 2016 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Thu May 12 12:14:00 BRT 2016 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT: javax.ejb.EJBException: Unexpected Error
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:163) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.TimerCMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(TimerCMTTxInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:101) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:132) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.isValid(I)Z
    at CargaDados.cx.gov.br.controle.CargaDadosC.CargaC(CargaDadosC.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:34) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: The problem seems to be similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673349/bad-version-of-db2jcc-jar-used-with-jre-1-7) question which has already an answer. It might help you.

Answer (score 9):

The isValid method was added in JDBC 4.0.  It appears you are using `db2jcc.jar` (JDBC 3.0) rather than `db2jcc4.jar` (JDBC 4.0).

Answer (score 0):

For me excluding HikariCP worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was long time ago but the cause is the use of jcc jar that does not support query validation functionality.

I was having following setting in my application.properties (Spring Boot):

```
db2.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
db2.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect
```

This would cause error described if I was using older version of jcc jar.

In my case, I can easily reproduce this issue:

- use **db2jcc jar** (in my case version 10.1) will result in this error
- use **db2jcc4.jar** and the error will not happen and isValid() executes fine